# Google Map Android V2 - How to use an online image at GroundOverlay?

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to use the [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay) functionality available at the [Google Maps Android API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). The image I want to show as an overlay, is available online only (because it is updated regularly); I cannot use a local resource. The example provided by Google, only shows how to use a local resource:

```
mGroundOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
            .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.newark_nj_1922)).anchor(0, 1)
            .position(NEWARK, 8600f, 6500f));
```

How to use an online image by means of an url? What is the best way?

Comment: Related bug (?): http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4637

Answer (score 0):

I've used an AsyncTask where in doInBackground() method I download the image and in onPostExecute() I add the GroundOverlay with the downloaded bitmap

```
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        downloadedBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(output.toByteArray(), 0, output.toByteArray().length);
```